# select values from table

Tags: php, mysql

I have table with below entries.Now I want to select values with `timeset_id=0` & `timeset_id !=0`.

I want to select did_id except did_id=219.Like fields only with `timeset_id=0`

```
SELECT * FROM routing_relation WHERE account_id = 36;
+-----+------------+--------+------------+----------+--------------+------------+-------------+
| id  | account_id | did_id | timeset_id | route_id | routing_type | voice_file | voice_file2 |
+-----+------------+--------+------------+----------+--------------+------------+-------------+
| 302 |        36  |    183 |          0 |        8 | ER           |            |             |
| 301 |        36  |    179 |          0 |        7 | ER           |            |             |
| 305 |        36  |    185 |          0 |       11 | ER           |            |             |
| 293 |        36  |    160 |          0 |       35 | ER           |            |             |
| 295 |        36  |    162 |          0 |        1 | ER           |            |             |
| 306 |        36  |    219 |          2 |       12 | ER           |            |             |
| 297 |        36  |    165 |          0 |        3 | ER           |            |             |
| 307 |        36  |    219 |          0 |       13 | ER           |            |             |
| 303 |        36  |    184 |          0 |        9 | ER           |            |             |
| 299 |        36  |    167 |          0 |        5 | ER           |            |             |
+-----+------------+--------+------------+----------+--------------+------------+-------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer should be like this

```
| did_id | timeset_id |
|    183 |          0 | 
|    179 |          0 | 
|    185 |          0 | 
|    160 |          0 | 
|    162 |          0 | 
|    165 |          0 | 
|    184 |          0 | 
|    167 |          0 |
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Please add your SQL statement to your question.

Comment: could you provide what ur output should be

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `timeset_id=0` & `timeset_id !=0` ? What do you want ?

Comment: `Select * from routing_relation where did_id <> '219' and timeset_id = '0'`

Comment: Since my first answer is a basic query like `Select * from routing_relation where did_id <> '219'` I think there is something more you are trying to ask. What is the logic behind `timeset_id=0 & timeset_id !=0`? You are getting all the timeset_id values this way!

Comment: i want to get  did_id except 219 which is having timeset_id=0 and timeset_id=2.Entries only with  timeset_id=0.

Comment: I want data of did_id where did_id =0 only.

Comment: 2 upvotes, and 3 close votes. Gotta love SO

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right - timeset_id=0 & timeset_id !=0 are making it you want to select all.
Then you want to have did_id=219, but only if timeset_id=0.

```
SELECT * FROM routing_relation WHERE account_id=36 AND NOT ( did_id=219 AND timeset_id<>0)
```

Comment: I don't want data of which did_id is multiple time.only of timeset_id=0. And did _id varies.Not only 219 .

Comment: That query should do just that - first select all records. Then discard all records where did_id=219 and at the same time tieset_id is not 0. So did_id different than 219 and different timeset_id will be included, as well as did_id=219 AND timeset_id=0.

Answer (score 0):

To select only with timeset_id=0:

```
SELECT * FROM routing_relation where account_id=36 AND timeset_id=0;
```

To select only with timeset_id != 0:

```
SELECT * FROM routing_relation where account_id=36 AND timeset_id<>0;
```

To select timeset_id=0 and not equal to did_id = 219:

```
SELECT did_id, timeset_id FROM routing_relation where account_id=36 AND timeset_id=0 AND did_id<>219;
```

It is everything I can say.

Comment: This doesn't work since OP wants to have both in the same query and wants did_id not equal to 219...

Comment: `SELECT * FROM routing_relation where account_id=36 AND timeset_id=0 AND did_id<>219;` May be it will help?

Comment: You are still missing the point that he wants both timeset_id =0 and <>0 in the same time (for what he says). Ps edit your answer, don't put answer in comments

Comment: @LelioFaieta i have posted the answer which i want

Comment: @soni8010 I see that my query `SELECT did_id, timeset_id FROM routing_relation where account_id=36 AND timeset_id=0 AND did_id<>219;` makes right the answer('Answer should be like this') you've posted in your question. You should accept this answer or modify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM routing_relation 
WHERE account_id = 36 
AND did_id != 219 
AND timeset_id = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Basing on comments your query is the following

```
SELECT id, account_id, did_id, timeset_id, route_id, routing_type
FROM routing_relation
WHERE account_id = 36 AND timeset_id=0 AND did_id<>219
```

Try and see if it is what you want. Obviously you can change the list of fields selected to your need.

Comment: No.that not what i want

Comment: what is the difference between my result and the desired one?